# Killing Molly in GTAV

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

WARNING !!! SPOILER ALERT. IF YOU HAVEN'T DONE SOLOMON'S MISSIONS (S ON MAP) DON'T READ :)

At the end of the mission in which you deliver the cars (the mission in which we take down police from the bond style car with Trevor driving the trailer and Franklin in the car), Molly denies you any money and rides off. However, once we get control of our character, we can still see her car and can also see it if we quickly take the car parked right next to Molly. I tried chasing her down, and could keep up till the time I messed up and hit the divider. Is there any way to get to her and ahem.. kill her before Michael's revenge?

P.S. this is the first time I am playing GTAV and keep messing up when chasing her every time I try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that would be possible. The game developers have made the game keeping such things in mind. I once tried to kill Amanda (Michael's wife) ; and I was successful in doing so by crushing her with a car.  But after I left the place I received a message on my phone from Amanda saying that I will have to pay the hospital bills. And that's what I think will happen if you try to kill Molly before she is supposed to die. Whether you receive a SMS from her about the incident that you tried to kill her or not, but she will be there alive in the mission when Michael chases her.

Comment: Have you tried doing that? Because when I tried the same thing with those stupid minute men, their car just doesn't blast!!

Comment: Try killing her when you don't have michael, and see the magic

Comment: So you tried killing them by blasting their car but they didn't die. That's what I am saying: The characters which are supposed to die later will not die unless the game story wants that. Either they will not die whether you blast them or shoot them, or they it will seem that they have died but later they become alive

Comment: But what about Dom? He dies if you shoot a rocket and his missions never appear!!

Comment: @darkangel that's because they are side missions, not necessary for the main story, and you can still do the parachute jumps without him

Comment: https://youtu.be/XvfSHgTeTGQ

Answer (score 1):

> At the end of the mission in which you deliver the cars (the mission in which we take down police from the bond style car with Trevor driving the trailer and Franklin in the car)

The mission that you are describing is [Pack Man](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Pack_Man), where you grab the vehicles stolen on previous missions and deliver them to the Procopio Truck Stop.

> Is there any way to get to her and ahem.. kill her before Michael's revenge?

Canonically, Molly dies at the end of the mission [Legal Trouble](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Legal_Trouble) so is not possible to kill her *permanently* during or after Pack Man.

If you really want to kill her after Pack Man, try to use a [Railgun](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Railgun) after the cutscene ends. The Railgun has the higher projectile speed for all explosive weapons and should be more than enough to blow the car up (I have not tested it).

Comment: Yeah, 'bout that. If you aim is real good, as my hardcore friend showed me, you CAN kill Molly just before she goes near the plane by shooting her in the head, but, ironically the mission fails